# Show list of relations between turtles and patches

Tags: netlogo

In the model every turtle and patches has certain value. Then by making a comparisión of the two values I get a new one. So I need to get the full list of the combinations (turtle-patch, and their values) that arise  in the model.

Comment: When you say 'list', do you mean you want a data type `list` variable (like the answer below), or a list in the output (like a printed list)?

Answer (score 1):

It is not entirely clear what you want, but this example will probalby suffice.  Let's use color as an example, because it is present by default.

```
[(list self color patch-here pcolor)] of turtles
```

**Edit:**

You can substitute any list of characteristics you wish.  Try it!  E.g.

```
[(list who color pxcor pycor pcolor)] of turtles
```

Note that is you are thinking of this as documenting a mapping from turtles to the rest of the variables, you probably should use the `table` extension.

Comment: What I want is to see a list that shows "the patch" where the turtles are located, and the values that were given to them (the turtle and the patch).

Something like list where I could see "who value pxcor pycor value"